# changes() not called when inserting a document

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have a problem with the changelog function of rethinkdb. There is no console output, when adding a document to the collection. **BUT** "changes" is outputted once after starting my application via `node app.js`, why is that so? Any help is appreciated.

```
// rethinkdb connection
var connection = null;
r.connect({ db: 'bc', host: 'localhost', port: 1337}, function(err, conn) {
    if(err) throw err;

    connection = conn;
    observeBets();
});


function observeBets() {
    r.table('bets').changes().run(connection, function(err, betsCursor) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log("changes");
    });
}
```

Insert via

```
var bet = {
    bet: "test",
    userID: 213
};
r.table('bets').insert(bet);
```

Comment: Running the changes() query via the Data Explorer works as expected, so there must be a node problem I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to be iterating over `betsCursor`.

Comment: But why? Isnt it just a callback function which should be called thus `console.log ("changes")` should be called?

Comment: The callback isn't called once per change, it's called once when you've *finished subscribing to changes*, and it's passed a cursor.  If you call `bestCursor.each(callback2)`, then `callback2` will be called for every change.